# React Rest Call Infinite Loop Using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am noticing that my component is stuck in an infinite loop. It keeps making the same rest call.

It is my understanding that `useEffect` hooks work similar to ComponentRender and ComponentUpdate lifecycle functions.

Also, I think what is happening is this but not able to fix it:

On render - > API called -> Updated Error state -> Component Updated -> UseEffect Hooked called again

Can you help me?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./ResultsPage.css";
import Error from "../components/Error";

function Homepage() {
  let username = "test";

  const [error, setError] = useState({ exists: false, value: null });
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  const getUsernameData = () => {
    fetch(`testAPI/${username}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 404) {
          return setError({ exists: true, value: response.status });
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((json) => setUserData(json))
      .catch((error) => {
        setError({ active: true, type: 400 });
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsernameData();
  });

  return (
    <div className="Homepage">
      {error.exists && <Error error={error} username={username} />}
      {!error.exists && <h1>Error does not exist</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` will run on every render unless you tell it otherwise. Your effect has no dependency array, so it is running every render, triggering a re-render, and then starting over again infinitely.

You can tell the `useEffect` to only run once on mount by giving it an empty array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getUsernameData();
}, []);
```

You can also tell it to only run when certain things change. Do this by adding the variables to the dependency array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getUsernameData();
}, [variable_to_depend_on]);
```

Comment: upvoting Brian's answer for including the 'why' as well as the the 'what'.

Comment: Thanks @Brian for taking your time to answer this in-depth!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing...

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUsernameData();
});
```

to

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUsernameData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you. For anyone wanting to know how it is done, follow this link : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: You should a) memoize your fetch function with useCallback and b) add it to your dependency array for useEffect. Or if not, you may wish to explain why....